# Javascript - return функции, в которой есть перебор массива

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

Создаю для MongoDb документ (карточка товара). В процессе выполнения функции, должна происходить запись нескольких фотографий этого товара. Вот здесь и возникла проблема - функция завершает свое выполнение раньше, чем происходит запись файлов. Даже один не успевает записаться). Ниже код, я его минимизировал:

```
function createGoods(dataGoods, callback) {
    var k = JSON.parse(dataGoods);
    var f = {};
    f.img =[];
    //этот цикл не успевает завершиться, прежде, чем произойдет возврат 
      функции
    for (let i=0; i<k.img.length; i++){
        createFile(data, pathWriteFile, nameFile, function(name){
            f.img.push(name);
        });
    }
    f.visible = true;
    f.path = h;
    .........

    return callback(f);

}
```

Модуль записи файла

```
function createFile(data, pathWriteFile, nameFile, callback){
    fs.writeFile(pathWriteFile, data, "base64",function(err){
        return callback(nameFile);
        })
}
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы решить эту проблему?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать *промисы* и возвращать значение только после выполнения списка промисов ([Promise.all](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)), либо (если через коллбэки) библиотеку `async` ([async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel)), либо нативные *async/await* ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)) если версия ноды позволяет.

Пример с промисами:

```js
console.log('Begin');
const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    asyncFunction(i, resolve);
  });
  promises.push(p);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); 
  console.log('End')
});

function asyncFunction(i, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("result: " + i);
    cb(i);
  }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Замени `fs.writeFile` на `fs.writeFileSync`.
Так ты избавишься от ассинхронности.

Comment: Стоит более полно описывать причины появления проблемы.